# Pointer data member initilized on the heap

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-allocation

I have a Node class and a NodeManager class. NodeManager objects hold a pointer to Node. I want this Node pointer to point to a Node object that is allocated on the heap. The heap allocation happens in `NodeManager.init()`.

Here's the code.

```
class Node
{
public:
    int index;
};

class NodeManager
{
public:
    NodeManager() {}
    void initNode(Node *b)
    {
        b = new Node();
    }

    Node *node;
};

int main()
{
    NodeManager manager;
    manager.initNode(manager.node);

    cout << manager.node << endl; //prints a bad pointer

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, when I change `initNode()` to:

```
void initNode()
{
    this->node = new Node();
}
```

the `manager` object actually "remembers" its `node`'s address.
The problem is that in the first code, the address isn't remembered and the application prints out a bad address. Why is that?

Edit:
To make things clearer, I'm working with a class that has a data member that is a pointer to an object. My class has a recursive member function that takes its data member pointer as a "starting point" parameter and keeps calling itself to allocate and create the object's "children" too. But then, I get this problem. the private data member isn't remembered and turns out to be NULL or a bad pointer after all.

Comment: If that's all `NodeManager` is, you're just trying to recreate a very limited smart pointer.

Comment: I suggest you review some existing examples of linked lists that are already posted to the internet.

Comment: Mathematician already provided the correct answer, but my question is why would you want to write your init function like that?

Comment: I edited my question to explain the real problem I'm having

Comment: Your edit really sounds like the member should be a smart pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to change the value of the pointer but you are passing it by *value*. As a consequence, it is the copy that is changed inside your function.

Pass by value creates a copy of the object passed to the function and any changes to it made within the function are only made to the *copy*. Pass the pointer by reference instead if you want to change the pointer with the function. Something like

```
void initNode(Node* &b)
{
    b = new Node();
}
```

Comment: I thought of that. But isn't really the point of pointers that data _doesn't_ get passed by value? What's next? pointers of pointers? I'm confused...

Comment: Passing a pointer to a function is a good way of allowing the function to modify what the pointer **points** to, not the pointer itself. You are explicitly trying to change the value of the **pointer** (i.e change the address), and passing by value will simply not do what you want. Sure it will change the address of the copy, but the copy no longer exists after the function exits

Comment: @Pilpel, Everything gets passed by value unless you use a reference, pointers included. The value of a pointer is an address. Copying an address means both pointers can access the data at that address, but changing the address stored in one copy won't affect which address is stored in the other copy.

Comment: @Pilpel `What's next? pointers of pointers?`  Yes.  `void initNode(Node**b) { *b = new Node(); }`  That is basically the same thing as the reference version.  The difference is that on the caller side, you pass the *address of the pointer*.